# LINQtoCSV | How to write text at the end of the CSV File

Tags: c#, csv, linqtocsv

Is it possible to write data at the end of the csv file or one line after the end of the csv file when using LINQToCSV library.

I am using LINQtoCSV and passing a List<> to write the data. my List<> is like

```
x    y    z

1    4    5

1    5    3
```

Now i want to do y*z for each record and write the sum at the end of the csv file.

```
Sum = 35
```

i Have been searching this for a while but didn't quite find any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/00c609c0-5048-4ef1-8c03-e7c6217d8a32/n-not-working-in-fileappendalltext?forum=csharpgeneral

```
File.AppendAllText(csvPath, "");
```

did the trick.

**EDIT:**

I looped through all the List records and collected the Sum of y*z.

```
sum = 0;
for (int i= 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
    sum += (y * z);

File.AppendAllText(csvPath, String.Concat("Sum = ", sum.ToString()));
```

For writing on one line after the end of the csv File, Environment.NewLine can be used

```
File.AppendAllText(csvPath, Environment.NewLine);
File.AppendAllText(csvPath, String.Concat("Sum = ", sum.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you're after, but I have used something like this in the past:

```
CsvContext csv = new CsvContext();
var models = csv.Read<CsvData>(@"c:\Icons\Windows7\Desktop\Book2.csv").ToList();
CsvData sum = new CsvData();
sum.z = models.Sum(m => m.y * m.z);
models.Add(sum);
csv.Write(models, @"c:\Icons\Windows7\Desktop\Book3.csv");
```

Where my model in this example was:

```
public class CsvData
{
    [CsvColumn(FieldIndex = 0)]
    public int x { get; set; }
    [CsvColumn(FieldIndex = 1)]
    public int y { get; set; }
    [CsvColumn(FieldIndex = 2)]
    public int z { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Don't you hate it when you do all that work to contribute your time freely, and the person who asks the question doesn't even give you a +1 for your time? So, I did.

Comment: Haha yeah but what you gonna do! Thanks!